# Angular first loading route not work in CefSharp

Tags: angular, cefsharp

I'm hosting some angular framework based web application in `CefSharp` as localfile(not localhost or nginx host). 
I have two angular routes: `HelloA` and `HelloB`.

After setting `ChromiumWebBrowser.Address` as `(myfilepotocal:\local-pc\index.html\#\HelloA)`, I can not direct to `HelloA` page. Only a blank page appears.

Comment: Can you try opening your file directly in chrome? Does it work there? Any errors in console?

Comment: It is a CefSharp ResourceHandler, can not access from browser.

Comment: Look at the log file to see if there is anything meaningful https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Trouble-Shooting#log-file past that you will need to provide more details, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example